# open eps files in GIMP2

Tags: ghostscript, gimp, eps

I have installed `GIMP 2.8.10` and `Ghostscript 9.14` for Windows X64. I am using windows 8.1 with update 1. I have also set the environment variable for `GS_PROG` to `gswin64c`. But I still cannot open `eps` files using `GIMP`. So how to solve the issue?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your `GS_PROG` environment variable to `C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.14\bin\gswin64.exe`

Comment: This should either be a comment, or be expanded upon a bit to make it a proper answer.

Comment: It's short, but looks like an attempt at a solution.  I don't know if it's correct, but it looks good enough to me to keep as an answer.

Comment: I use the 32 bit version of GS and the above environment variable setting works for me. Have you tried the 32 bit version as well (although I do not believe that this does make a difference)?